# Why am I getting this error "FirebaseRecyclerAdapter() in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied to:"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am developing an app with posts and am using Firebase as my backend platform.
 As followed, I tried to add the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, followed the instructions as given but am getting this error, that the guy in the video isn't, and I am not being able to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.shrinkio.Fragments.HomeFragment;
import com.example.shrinkio.Fragments.MessagesFragment;
import com.example.shrinkio.Fragments.NotFragment;
import com.example.shrinkio.Fragments.PeopleFragment;
import com.example.shrinkio.R;
import com.example.shrinkio.SecondaryActivities.DrawerLayout;
import com.example.shrinkio.SecondaryActivities.PostActivity;
import com.example.shrinkio.SecondaryActivities.Posts;
import com.example.shrinkio.SecondaryActivities.ProfileActivity;
import com.example.shrinkio.SecondaryActivities.SettingsActivity;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.Objects;

import static com.example.shrinkio.R.menu.main_menu;


public class BottomActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton Rd1, Rd2, Rd3, Rd4;
    RecyclerView rv;



    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private StorageReference StorageRef;

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private DatabaseReference mDataBase;


    @SuppressLint({"RtlHardcoded", "ClickableViewAccessibility"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MultiDex.install(this);


        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_bottom );
        new GestureOverlayView( this );

        //Action bar configurations
        Objects.requireNonNull( getSupportActionBar() ).setDisplayOptions( ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView( R.layout.abs_layout_home );




        //Navigation view
        NavigationView nav_view;
        nav_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);   //select nav_view from activity_drawer_layout
        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View nav_header = nav_view.getHeaderView(0);


        rv = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");



        //Navigation Drawer header menu items on click actions

        LinearLayout header = nav_header.findViewById( R.id.nav_header);
        header.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity( new Intent( BottomActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class ) );
            }
        } );

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        //I added this if statement to keep the selected fragment when rotating the device
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>()
                .setQuery(mDataBase, Posts.class)
                .build();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Posts, PostViewHolder> (
                Posts.class,
                R.layout.posts,
                PostViewHolder.class,
                mDataBase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position, Posts model) {
            holder.setPost(model.getPost());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.posts, parent, false);

                return new PostViewHolder(view);
            }
        };




        rv.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }


    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View mview;

        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mview = itemView;
        }

        public void setPost(String post) {
            TextView post_title = mview.findViewById(R.id.post);
            post_title.setText(post);
        }
    }



    //Define the options menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add){
                startActivity(new Intent(this, PostActivity.class));
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    // Bottom Navigation View, when the fragment is selected
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                            selectedFragment = new NotFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_people:
                            selectedFragment = new PeopleFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_messages:
                            selectedFragment = new MessagesFragment();
                    }

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }
            };


    // Navigation menu items on click action
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected (@NonNull MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                startActivity( new Intent( BottomActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class ) );
                overridePendingTransition( 0, 0 );
                return true;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                startActivity( new Intent( BottomActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class ) );
                overridePendingTransition( 0, 0 );
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I am getting the error that I typed in the question. 
 None of the answers on StackOverflow worked for me, that's why I am making a new post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Posts, PostViewHolder> (
                Posts.class,
                R.layout.posts,
                PostViewHolder.class,
                mDataBase
        )
```

Into this:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Posts, PostViewHolder> (options)
```

In the new version of Firebaseui, the constructor of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` take a parameter of type `FirebaseRecyclerOption` which you already initialized

Check the documentation:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#firebaseui-for-realtime-database

Comment: So I don't put the options inside the parameters?

Comment: Remove ur parameters and add option

Comment: As said in the answer... Change ur code into the code I gave u

Comment: Ok the error disappeared but does it do the same thing?

Comment: I added everything, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Method to start the activity seems to be missing. Try including the below code in `onStart()` method:

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter uses an event listener to monitor changes to the Firebase query.

For listening for data, call adapter.startListening(). Detailed information is available on the below link

[**FirebaseRecyclerAdapter lifecycle**](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#firebaserecycleradapter-lifecycle)

Comment: I did that, but it still appears the same error.